# Substitute range value of 8 cells in a different sheet with one search criteria as google app script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

unfortunately, my knowledge of Google app script programming is very weak and I need help as follows:
My function to find the right row in sheet2 with the search criteria from sheet works fine and now I need help to substitute exact these founded cells in the row.
First of all the function I use

```
function searchAndReplace(text, sheetName) {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt3"); //data range in this sheet
 const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1"); // search criteria in this sheet
 const text2 = sheet.getRange("I14:R14").getValues(); //range of new values
 const textFinder = sheet2.createTextFinder(text);
 const cell = textFinder.findNext();

 const row = cell.getRow();

 sheet2
   .getRange(`A${row}:${row}`)
   .activate();

}

function runsies2(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
  const text = sheet.getRange("M9").getValue();  //search criteria in M9
  
  const sheetName = "Tabellenblatt3";
  searchAndReplace(text, sheetName)
  
}
```

what do I have to do, to change the cell values of the activated row in sheet2 with the cell values of text2 (Range I14:R14) from sheet

I tried something with `.replaceAllWith(text2)` but everything went into a fault.
I also tried `sheet.getRange("I14:R14").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(`A${row}:${row}`));`
but then there are results in the cells did not fit to the range

Comment: Have you tried looping through the list of cells you found, and then performing your replacements? Something like `var range = sheet2.getRange(``A${row}:${row}``); var values = range.getValues(); values.forEach(function(row) {  row.forEach(cell) { /* do something with cell */ });  }); `.

Comment: I solved it now with   const row = cell.getRow();
 sheet.getRange("I14:R14").copyTo(sheet2
 .getRange(`A${row}:${row}`));
 var range = sheet2.getRange(`A${row}:${row}`);
 var values = range.getValues();